# Does Bootstrap 3 and IE 9 support jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, twitter-bootstrap-3

I started a new 2012 ASP.NET project and added Bootstrap 3 to it. I tried getting the dropdown menu to work, so I included the bootstrap.js file. But it gives me an error as soon as I run the project.

[image: Bootstrap 3, JS Error]

I went to the Bootstrap site and saw that it supports IE9. And running the Bootstrap site in IE9 works just fine.

[image: Bootstrap 3 IE 9 Support]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, here?

Comment: Hey, i hope you are loading jquery.min.js ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Icarus stated, it is most likely due to the order of your includes. jQuery must come first, so either in your page where you've included it, or in the Bundles.config make sure that you have them in the correct order.

Comment: seems like that poster may have removed their answer??

Comment: It looks like Icarus removed his answer. Because that was definitely the issue. Thanks!